# Can bicycles be taken on the ferry from Incheon to China?

Tags: china, south-korea, ferries, bicycles

I am planning a bicycle tour through Asia and want to take my bike on the ferry from Incheon (South Korea) to China (specific city in China doesn’t matter for me).

Does anyone have experience with taking a bicycle on the ferry? Do Chinese Customs allow visitors to take a bike into the country? If troublesome, I might need to change plans and take a flight instead.

Comment: I think there's little reason to believe that a bike wouldn't be allowed, provided it fits the size and weight requirements of the shipping company. At immigration you will face any problems.

Comment: Chinese Customs operate both at harbours and airports. Should there be a restriction on bicycles, and I don't believe there is, it would apply at all ports of entry.

Comment: Oops, I meant you will *not* face any problems. I have seen people bringing bicycles to China many times...

Answer (score 5):

Chinese Customs operate both at harbours and airports. Should there be a restriction on bicycles, and I don't believe there is, it would apply at all ports of entry.

The reason I don't believe there are restrictions on (temporary) importation of bicycles for personal use is that I see it done every time I go to Shenzhen from HK. Cyclists, all decked in bright gear, taking their bicycles to Shenzhen to ride.